# Find specific <li> in <div><ul>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try extract price "2 890 000Kč" and "Address" from this HTML (there are 12 same:

```
<div class="list-items__content list-items__content__1">
        <div class="list-items__content__in">
            <a href="#" class="in-heart js-heart " data-tooltip="Přidat do oblíbených" onclick="toggleFavorite(1234, this)">
                <i class="icon icon__heart-grey"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="list-items__content__in">
                                <h2 class="list-items__item__title list-items__item__title__1" itemprop="name">
                    <a href="/url/..." itemprop="url" class="js-simulate-link-target" onclick="return loadPropertyToModal(1234);" title="house value">
                        Some text about house </a>
                </h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    2 890 000Kč                    </li>
                <li>
                    Address                        </li>
            </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried it this way:

```
cena = soup.select(".list-items__content__in > li:nth-child(0)")
print(cena)
```

Output: []

Need print: 2 890 000 Kč, Address

How to get only value from first li tag (2 890 000Kč) and second li tag value (Address)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cena = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").select(".list-items__content__in > ul > li")
print([c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena])
```

Output:

```
['2 890 000Kč', 'Address']
```

EDIT:

You can `join()` the output:

```
print(" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena))
```

Output:

```
2 890 000Kč Address
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works! But it instead of ['2 890 000Kč', 'Address'] I need the result in the format Output: 2 890 000Kč Address. Because i have many others values to add them into one print.

Comment: do u know how to do it?

Comment: Thank you, works. And if i want these values separe one to one? Print(price), Print(address)?

Comment: Use this: `print("\n".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena))`

Comment: it separe, but i need them into one Print but separe values. Because i insert them into Google sheet and from this code they are in one cell. Is there way to do that twice? One for price, second for address?... I just write to print(price), print(address) for example.

Comment: If you're using Google sheets then it might be best to use a list. Ask another question to clarify your problem. Comments are not meant to debug code.