# insert value from format ['price, 'address'] into Google Sheets cell

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

Information about values are in this question: [Find specific <li> in <div><ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771267/find-specific-li-in-divul)

I try insert value ['price', 'address'] into Google Sheets, but show me error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:/....py", line 62, in <module>
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow,2)
 File "C:\...py", line 1523, in insert_row 
    return self.insert_rows([values], index, value_input_option='RAW')
  File "C:...py", line 1560, in insert_rows
    return self.spreadsheet.values_append(range_label, params, body)
  File "C:\...py", line 165, in values_append
    r = self.client.request('post', url, params=params, json=body)
  File "...py", line 76, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid values[1][3]: list_value {\n  values {\n    string_value: "2 890 000K\\304\\215"\n  }\n  values {\n    string_value: "Address\\303\\275ch hrdin\\305\\257, Address\\303\\255n, Address\\303\\255n Address"\n  }\n}\n', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
PS C:\...>
```

How to convert value ['price', 'address'] into text (like 'price', 'addres') before inserting to Google Sheets?

I try this:

```
insertRow = ["value", value,'', [c.getText(strip=True) for c in price], str(value), value]
sheet.insert_row(insertRow,2)
```

but this `[c.getText(strip=True) for c in price]` not working and showing error.

Comment: What module do you use to work with Google sheets?

Comment: @baduker i have another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778948/split-list-to-diferent-cells-in-google-sheets) this is only for error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is use **join**:

```
" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena)
```

Because inserting list into one cell not accepted with Google Sheets (show me this error).

Thanks for help to @baduker.