# split list to diferent cells in Google Sheets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

I have cells in Google Sheets:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8SWl.png)

I need separe price, address to have:

Name1 = 1run, Name2 = price, Name3 = address, Name4 = message

I have this code (question is there [Find specific <li> in <div><ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771267/find-specific-li-in-divul)):

```
print(" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena))
```

It print (I use it in insert to GS) like: *price address* in one cell

How to do that, to print only price to column Name2, and second print(or insert) into Name3?

**Edit:**

This code I use for running .py script:

```
import gspread
import requests
import datetime 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import timedelta
import time

datetime.datetime.now()

stranka =1
stranka_1 = '/'

scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]


while stranka < 5:
    URL = 'url_address_here' + stranka_1
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    #headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0'}
    #response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    pocet_bytu = 0

    #Google Sheet
    data = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("data.json", scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(data)
    sheet = client.open("rrfile).worksheet('site_name_sheet')
    data = sheet.get_all_records()

    #log
    sheet2 = client.open("rrfile").worksheet('LOG')
    data = sheet2.get_all_records()

    insertRow = ["site, "START: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y ve %H:%M:%S'))]
    sheet2.insert_row(insertRow,2)

    #Scraping web site
    results = soup.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'list-items__item'})
    for job_data in results:
        n = job_data.find('a', attrs={'class':'js-simulate-link-target'})
        n_final = n.text.strip()

        url = job_data.find('a', attrs={"class":"js-simulate-link-target"})
        url_pred_final = url.get('href')
        url_final = "site_url" + url_pred_final

        cena = job_data.select(".list-items__content__in > ul > li")

        pocet_bytu += 1

        #přidání řádku do sheetu
        insertRow = ["site", n_final,'', " ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena), str(pocet_bytu), url_final]
        
        print(insertRow)
        sheet.insert_row(insertRow,2)

    insertRow = ["site", "KONEC: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y ve %H:%M:%S'))]
    sheet2.insert_row(insertRow,2)
    stranka +=1
    stranka_1 = '/page-' + str(stranka) + '/'
    print(stranka_1)
    print(URL)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Output is:

**site, n_value,'', price address, 1, url**

But i need split price and address each of them alone to cell, so i need output:

**site, n_value, '', price, address, 1, url**

Is there a way to split in inserRow when I have one value (u can see in question up - how to get these values price, address)?

**Edit2:**
There are 10 this element on the web page. Another on next pages. There change only price and Address - but same for every these code.

```
<div class="list-items__content list-items__content__1">
            <div class="list-items__content__in">
                <a href="#" class="in-heart js-heart " data-tooltip="Přidat do oblíbených" onclick="toggleFavorite(8826547, this)">
                    <i class="icon icon__heart-grey"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="list-items__content__in">
                                    <h2 class="list-items__item__title list-items__item__title__1" itemprop="name">
                        <a href="url" itemprop="url" class="js-simulate-link-target" onclick="return loadPropertyToModal(8826547);" title="some text">
                            some another text</a>
                    </h2>
<!--                -->
<!--                <p>--><!--</p>-->

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        price1                    </li>

<!--                    -->                    <li>
<!--                        --><!-- Kč/m<sup>2</sup>-->
                        Address1</li>
<!--                    -->                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Edit:
Try answer from @Nikko J.:**

When I try your code, it print me all values price and addres of all values from website. I mean:

One block element have price1... address1.
Second block element have price2... address2.
.
.
.

So the output is like:

```
['site', 1, '', price1, address1, price2, address2,..., 456654]
['site', 2, '', price1, address1, price2, address2,..., 456654]
['site', 3, '', price1, address1, price2, address2,..., 456654]
['site', 4, '', price1, address1, price2, address2,..., 456654]
```

I need only print price and address for the block, not all values for all blocks, so like:

```
['site', 1, '', price1, address1, 456654]
['site', 2, '', price2, address2, 456654]
['site', 3, '', price3, address3, 456654]
['site', 4, '', price4, address4, 456654]
```

Comment: What package are you using? Could you include more snippet of your code?

Comment: @Nikko J. I edit question. Thank you for help me to split these (one value) values into 2 cell, not one like with this code.

Comment: It is difficult for me to debug your code without the data. Is it possible for you to include the url? or at least the output of `page = requests.get(URL)`

Comment: @Nikko J. here in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771267/find-specific-li-in-divul are data, where i try to get price and address. But in final i need only split them. Is there any solution in split them in (" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena)). For example (" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena).limit=1) to take only first value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `" ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena)` with `[c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena[:2]]` and just flatten the list.

**Example:**

```
cena = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser").select(".list-items__content__in > ul > li")
insertRow = ["site", 1234,'',[c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena[:2]] , 456654, 32452]

def flatten_list(_2d_list):
    flat_list = []
    for element in _2d_list:
        if type(element) is list:
            for item in element:
                flat_list.append(item)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    return flat_list

print('insertRow value:', insertRow)
print('Transformed Flat List:', flatten_list(insertRow))
```

**Output:**

```
insertRow value: ['site', 1234, '', ['2 890 000Kč', 'Address'], 456654, 32452]
Transformed Flat List: ['site', 1234, '', '2 890 000Kč', 'Address', 456654, 32452]
```

**Reference:**

- [Stack Abuse - Python: How to Flatten a List of Lists](https://stackabuse.com/python-how-to-flatten-list-of-lists/)

### Edit:

From what I've understood, the content of `[c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena]` can have multiple sets of price and address.

You can use a  for loop statement that iterates by 2 and access each set by using the iterator.

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools
import datetime
text = """
<div class="list-items__content list-items__content__1">
   <div class="list-items__content__in">
      <a href="#" class="in-heart js-heart " data-tooltip="Přidat do oblíbených" onclick="toggleFavorite(8826547, this)">
      <i class="icon icon__heart-grey"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="list-items__content__in">
      <h2 class="list-items__item__title list-items__item__title__1" itemprop="name">
         <a href="url" itemprop="url" class="js-simulate-link-target" onclick="return loadPropertyToModal(8826547);" title="some text">
         some another text</a>
      </h2>
      <ul>
         <li>
            price1
         </li>
         <li>
            Address1
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="list-items__content list-items__content__1">
   <div class="list-items__content__in">
      <a href="#" class="in-heart js-heart " data-tooltip="Přidat do oblíbených" onclick="toggleFavorite(8826547, this)">
      <i class="icon icon__heart-grey"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="list-items__content__in">
      <h2 class="list-items__item__title list-items__item__title__1" itemprop="name">
         <a href="url" itemprop="url" class="js-simulate-link-target" onclick="return loadPropertyToModal(8826547);" title="some text">
         some another text</a>
      </h2>
      <ul>
         <li>
            price2
         </li>
         <li>
            Address2
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
"""

cena = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").select(".list-items__content__in > ul > li")
test = [c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena]
site = 1
for i in range(0,len(test),2):
   data = test[i:i+2]
   insertRow = ["site", site,'', data[0], data[1] , 456654]
   site = site+1
   print('insertRow value:', insertRow)
```

**Output:**

```
insertRow value: ['site', 1, '', 'price1', 'Address1', 456654]
insertRow value: ['site', 2, '', 'price2', 'Address2', 456654]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I try it, but it print all values into one line per lines. I add into my question what i mean.

Comment: What is the content of ` ".join(c.getText(strip=True) for c in cena)` per each iteration? Because the solution I gave you is based on the example you've provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771267/find-specific-li-in-divul) and it only has ['2 890 000Kč', 'Address']

Comment: I add Edit2 into Question. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Triliang123 - Correct me if I'm wrong, your goal is to get the first set of price and address in variable `cena`? For example in your `cena` you have `price1, address1, price2, address2`, you only want the price1 and address1?

Comment: Yes, i need to get first price and address for block of element. In the whole code u can see for job_data in results: - there I try every block (where are price and address and another values) to get one line code to insert into google sheets. After i start skript, start inserting line by line, but with your code get me all price and addres for every lines. Is it ok to underestand? :) I know, it hard to say without url addres, but site is not public for everyone.

Comment: @Triliang123 - I fixed that by adding `cena[:2]` to the for loop. This will get the first 2 elements of `cena`. See updated answer above.

Comment: It get only first value price and address, but not for every element each of blocks. How u can see in Edit: Try answer from @Nikko J.: there are 'site', 1, '', price1, address1, 456654 then code in for job_data runs again and take another block with values 'site', 2, '', price2, address2, 456654 and another, another... I need get second price, address, then price2, address2.

Comment: @Triliang123 - You need to iterate the content of `cena`. See my updated answer above.